# how can I get the binary parsed tree from coreNLP parser?

Tags: binary-tree, stanford-nlp

I need the binary parse tree of an sentence to do my experiment. But after I used Stanford Parser and CoreNLP parser, I got non-binary tree. I have tried   to add propertiy "parse.binaryTrees": "true", but it didn't work. I also have tried to startup a server in commanline like "-binarize", it also failed!!
So how can I get a binary tree from parser??

> java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP.properties  -port 9000 -timeout 15000

```
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP(r'/home/lsl/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05')
output = nlp.annotate(sentence, properties={'annotators': 'parse',
                                             'parse.binaryTrees': 'true',
                                            'outputFormat': 'json'})
```

I want to use python to solve this problem. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

```
def binarize(tree):
    """
    Recursively turn a tree into a binary tree.
    """
    if isinstance(tree, str):
        return tree
    elif len(tree) == 1:
        return binarize(tree[0])
    else:
        label = tree.label()

        return reduce(lambda x, y: (binarize(x), binarize(y)), tree)

t = Tree.fromstring("(ROOT (S (S (VP (VBD ليس) (ADVP (RB هناك)) (SBAR (WHNP (WP ما)) (S (VP (VBN يمنع) (PP (IN من) (NP (NN اخذ) (NP (DTNNS المكملات) (DTJJ الغذائية))))))))) (CC و) (S (NP (DTNNS البروتين)) (NP (NN شرط) (SBAR (SBAR (IN ان) (S (VP (VBP تكون) (ADJP (JJ مسجلة))))) (CC و) (SBAR (S (VP (VN موافق) (PP (IN على) (NP (PRP ها))) (PP (IN من) (NP (NP (NN وزارة) (NP (DTNN الصحة))) (CC او) (NP (NN مؤسسة) (NP (DTNN الغذاء) (CC و) (DTNN الدواء))) (CC و) (NP (NN دون) (NP (NP (NN مبالغة)) (PP (IN في) (NP (DT ذلك))))))))))))) (PUNC ;) (S (PP (PP (IN في) (NP (DTNN الاونة) (DTJJ الاخيرة))) (CC و) (PP (IN في) (NP (NOUN_QUANT معظم) (NP (DTNN البلدان) (DTJJ العربية))))) (VP (VBD اصبح) (VP (VBP يتسلل) (PP (IN ل) (NP (NN اسواق) (NP (PRP$ ها)))) (NP (NP (NN اصناف) (NP (NN غير) (JJ مرخصة))) (CC و) (NP (NN غير) (NP (NN مسموح)))) (PP (IN ب) (NP (PRP ها)))))) (CC و) (S (VP (VBN لوحظ) (NP (NOUN_QUANT بعض) (NP (DTNNS المضاعفات))) (PP (IN على) (NP (DTNN القلب) (CC و) (DTNN الكلى))))) (PUNC ;) (FRAG (VBP ينصح) (NP (NN عدم) (NP (NN اخذ) (NP (NP (NNS مكملات) (JJ غذائية)) (PP (PP (IN من) (NP (NN تحت) (NP (DTNN الطاولة)))) (CC او) (PP (IN من) (NP (NN خلال) (NP (NN صديق))))))))) (PUNC .)))")

bt = binarize(t)

print(bt)
```